# How can I get the headline of Frankfurt theme in Warsaw theme?

Tags: beamer

Is it possible to modify a Warsaw theme to get the section indicator like Frankfurt? In the image below, the style is Warsaw, but I would like to have the section indicator to the right of the section name in the blue segment.
So,.... Introduction    circle  circle circle

Is it possible? Please let me know[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, to know how, we have to look into the file `beamerthemeFrankfurt.sty` and see which outer theme is loaded, as this normally defines the `headline`. In the file we see:

```
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
```

And then we have to dig into `beamerouterthemesmoothbars.sty` to see how the `headline` template is called and we can find:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{smoothbars theme}
```

So what we need to do is, load the `smoothbars theme` first, then load `Warsaw` and then set the beamertemplate `headline` to our liking, which is the `smoothbars theme`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[smoothbars theme]

\author{TeX.SE}
\title{How to use headline of Frankfurt in Warsaw theme?}

\begin{document}
    
\frame{\titlepage}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{1}
\frame{Introduction}
\subsection{2}
\frame{Introduction}
\subsection{3}
\frame{Introduction}

\section{Methods}
\subsection{1}
\frame{Methods}

\section{Results}
\subsection{1}
\frame{Results}

\section{Conclusion}
\subsection{1}
\frame{Conclusion}
    
\end{document}
```

This results in:
[image]